# ScrollView doesn't work in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have two labels in ViewController, one of them dynamically change, because length of data is different(I get data from JSON file). 
I tried use 
`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` 
but doesn't work.
I added ScrollView to my ViewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
NSLog(@"hjgjgjk==%@",detailArray);

NSDictionary *dictionary = [detailArray mutableCopy];
expressionLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"expression"];

meaningLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"meaning"];
```

Could you explain me, which way should I go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you've added labels on scrollview.

Please add below line after adding text to labels.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Which in your case must be

```
NSLog(@"hjgjgjk==%@",detailArray);

NSDictionary *dictionary = [detailArray mutableCopy];
expressionLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"expression"];

meaningLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"meaning"];

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

My suggestion of doing this is like below:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView= [UIScrollView new];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    UILabel *scrollViewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    scrollViewLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    scrollViewLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollView addSubview:scrollViewLabel];

    scrollViewLabel.text = @"Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.";


    /*** Auto Layout ***/

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, scrollViewLabel);

    NSArray *scrollViewLabelConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollViewLabel(scrollView)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [scrollView addConstraints:scrollViewLabelConstraints];

    scrollViewLabelConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollViewLabel]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [scrollView addConstraints:scrollViewLabelConstraints];

    NSArray *scrollViewConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[scrollView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:scrollViewConstraints];

    scrollViewConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[scrollView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:scrollViewConstraints];
```

For two(or more views) labels set horizontally:

```
    UIScrollView *scrollView= [UIScrollView new];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    UILabel *scrollViewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    scrollViewLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    scrollViewLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollView addSubview:scrollViewLabel];

    UILabel *scrollViewLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    scrollViewLabel2.numberOfLines = 0;
    scrollViewLabel2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollView addSubview:scrollViewLabel2];

    scrollViewLabel.text = @"Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.";


  scrollViewLabel2.text = @"Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.Hi there.";

    /*** Auto Layout ***/

     //scrollviewLabel
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, scrollViewLabel, scrollViewLabel2);

    NSArray *scrollViewLabelConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollViewLabel(scrollView)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [scrollView addConstraints:scrollViewLabelConstraints];

    scrollViewLabelConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollViewLabel]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [scrollView addConstraints:scrollViewLabelConstraints];


    //scrollviewLabel2
    NSArray *scrollViewLabel2Constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                 constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[scrollViewLabel]-[scrollViewLabel2(==scrollViewLabel)]-|"
                                 options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil
                                 views:views];
    [scrollView addConstraints:scrollViewLabel2Constraints];


    //scrollview
    NSArray *scrollViewConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[scrollView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:scrollViewConstraints];

    scrollViewConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[scrollView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:scrollViewConstraints];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have problem now with display labels in DetailViewController, Could you please check my code ?https://goo.gl/ppA3AV

Comment: sure I'll check now.

Comment: and what do you think?

Comment: you need to change this - "NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, detailArray);"   to "NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, meaningLabel, expressionLabel);"

Comment: and you need to write constraints to every UIView either it may label/textfield/view etc.